# is retina working in my developer iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm testing my app in an iPhone5.

I duplicate an image, named image1.png and image1@2x.png, and tried it in iPhone5, in some part of my code:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] ;

CGFloat imageWidth = myImage.size.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = myImage.size.height;

  NSLog(@"image %f %f", imageWidth,imageHeight);

CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;


NSLog(@"screen %f %f", screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

and when running in the iphone, in the console I see:

```
2013-04-05 13:13:48.386 Vallabici[2413:907] image 320.000000 57.000000
2013-04-05 13:13:48.389 Vallabici[2413:907] screen 320.000000 568.000000
```

as it was using normal screen instead of retina.

how can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the image should not change on the retina device, just the scale.
To take the scale of the image add the following log:

```
 NSLog(@"scale %f", myImage.scale);
```

Answer (score 2):

`bounds` returns the size of the screen in points, not pixels

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds).

The same is true of `size`

Answer (score 1):

screens are always measured in pixel

and retina pixels are always = non retina pixel

by code you'll get always screen pixel of 230x480 (on iPhones < 5)

the difference is how images are rendered: on retina display they are rendered at double resolution

It's like printer devices: you can print a small image to an A4 paper filling it, and then print a bigger image...

images printed to paper have always the same measures (in inches or centimeters), but the quality of the results change